# Is there a way to take a variable from JS to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm wondering if there's a way to bring a variable from JS to PHP. I've got creating the variable in JS, I just wanna know if there's a way to bring it to PHP. HTML:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input class="mainwrite" id="userInput">
    <input type="submit" onclick="save()">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function save() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    alert(input);
}
```

I want to take the `input` variable and add it to a PHP file as a string.

Comment: **Hint**: pass the JS variable to the PHP script thru (1) form submission or (2) ajax .

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<script>
var var= "big boss";
</script>

<?php
echo "<script>document.writeln(var);</script>";
?>
```

Comment: This won't work. PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript after. The only way to get a variable from JS to PHP is via Ajax or submitting to request.

Comment: This doesn't provide the value `"big boss"` to PHP.  The only value PHP has is the literal string `"<script>document.writeln(var);</script>"`.  Additionally, naming a JavaScript variable `var` is just asking for a variety of problems.